# SQLAlchemy func issue with date and .isocalendar()

Tags: python, sqlite, date, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have a table that stores tasks submitted by users, with timestamps. I would like to write a query that returns certain rows based on when they were submitted (was it this day/week/month..).

To check if it was submitted on this week, I wanted to use `date.isocalendar()[1]` function. The problem is, that my timestamps are `datetime`s, so I would need to transform those to `date`s.

Using func:
`filter(func.date(Task.timestamp) == datetime.date(datetime.utcnow()))`
works properly.

But I need the `date` object's `isocalendar()` method, so I try

`filter(func.date(Task.timestamp).isocalendar()[1]==datetime.date(datetime.utcnow()).isocalendar()[1])`

and it's no good, I get `AttributeError: Neither 'Function' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'isocalendar'`

If I make a simple query and try `datetime.date(task.timestamp).isocalendar()[1]` it works properly.

How do I get it to work in the query's filter?

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb when understanding and debugging sqlalchemy queries is to always think – "How will it look in SQL?"

`isocalendar()` is a python function, and sqlalchemy query filters get compiled to SQL. Moreover, `isocalendar()` returns a tuple – and while rendering tuple comparison as SQL is probably possible, it's more trouble then it's worth. You should compare scalars and find sql date functions that suit you.

It seems you're looking to compare week number, so something like this should do the trick:

```
filter(func.week(Task.timestamp)==datetime.utcnow().isocalendar()[1])
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working, even if I added a [mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) as a parameter inside of `func.week`. It says there is no such function as `week`

Comment: Any function you 'call' on func gets translated to SQL directly, so your database should have it. I don't know what you are using, but you tagged as mysql, and mysql has it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: Yes, that is my fault, I am actually using SQLite, so thats why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `sqlalchemy.extract(func.date('year', Task.timestamp)) == ...` ?

Comment: `func.extract('week', func.date(Task.timestamp)) == ... ` works, but it returns one less than the iso format (today is the 19th week according to `isocalendar()` while according to this its the 18th). I can't find any documentation, is it just a difference because one starts counting from 0 while the other from 1, or is it something else? If its the former, I guess subtracting 1 from the iso format would solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix pure python functions with those which are executed on the `SQL` backend. From your code it looks like you are trying to filter on the `iso week`. One way to do it would be to load everything from the database into memory and perform the filtering there. Obviously, it most cases it is far from efficient.

An alternative would be to use respective `SQL` functions, which `sqlalchemy` will call for you. On `MySQL` it looks like the function you need is [`weekofyear`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear), so your filter might look similar to below:

```
_utcnow = datetime.utcnow().date()
_isoweek = _utcnow.isocalendar()[1]

q = db.session.query(...)
# ...
q = q.filter(db.func.weekofyear(Task.timestamp) == _isoweek)
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like to do. On the other hand, it throws me a `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such function: weekofyear 'SELECT ... ` I have `func` imported, maybe I am missing something else too ?

Comment: try `db.func.week(Task.timestamp, 3)` instead, maybe it has been introduced in later version of MySQL (and I do not have much knowledge of this RDBMS)